# Get social icons below paragraph block text

Tags: html, css

Please look at my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AnNyf

I am trying to get those icons to fit right under that block of text there on the right. I've tried a lot of methods but I just can't get it to work. I'm just a bit rusty on things so I need a refresher.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By right, you mean you want it to stay at the right or should disapper when they are shrinked which is happening right now?

Answer (score 0):

```
add right:300px to your li css class

header#header .inner .networks li {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top:122px;
    position: relative;
    right:300px; //recommend you play around with the value
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AnNyf/2/